# How to display Price Range Slider block to filter products

Tags: layered-navigation, filter, filterable-attributes

I used **AJAX Layered Navigation & Toolbar with Price Slider 2.2.0** Extension. But AJAX Price Slider is not displaying in frontend. It is showing in backend and update all required field to set price slider in front side. How to display AJAX Price Slider in frontend left navigation sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Price attribute displays in layered navigation by default in magento. check whether products are displaying or not, if yes then check the price of products.

No need to do any specific setting to display price attribute.